# Enable Touch Screen on Lenovo X1 Carbon Touch

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, thinkpad, touchscreen

There are quite a few guides on how to enable touch screens, but none with credentials or specifically to a ThinkPad device like the one I have.  Does anyone know how to enable it or know where I can find a good source?  Thanks!

Note:  I am on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Touch running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  It uses eGalax capacitive.